# Powershell: Turn period delimited string into object properties

Tags: powershell, properties, split

I have a string that looks something like this:

```
$string = "property1.property2.property3"
```

And I have an object, we'll call `$object`.  If I try to do `$object.$string` it doesn't interpret it that I want `property3` of `property2` of `property1` of `$object`, it thinks I want `$object."property1.property2.property3"`.

Obviously, using `split('.')` is where I need to be looking, but I don't know how to do it if I have an unknown amount of properties.  I can't statically do:

```
$split = $string.split('.')
$object.$split[0].$split[1].$split[2]
```

That doesn't work because I don't know how many properties are going to be in the string.  So how do I stitch it together off of `n` amounts of properties in the string?

Comment: Take a look at this post: [Set Value of Nested Object Property by Name in PowerShell](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46451994/3110834)

Answer (score 3):

A simple cheater way to do this would be to use `Invoke-Expression`. It will build the string and execute it in the same way as if you typed it yourself.

```
$string = "property1.property2.property3"
Invoke-Expression "`$object.$string"
```

You need to escape the first `$` since we don't want that expanded at the same time as `$string`. Typical warning: Beware of malicious code execution when using `Invoke-Expression` since it can do anything you want it to.

In order to avoid this you would have to build a recursive function that would take the current position in the object and pass it the next breadcrumb.

```
Function Get-NestedObject{
    param(
        # The object we are going to return a propery from
        $object,
        # The property we are going to return            
        $property,
        # The root object we are starting from.
        $rootObject
    )
    # If the object passed is null then it means we are on the first pass so 
    # return the $property of the $rootObject. 
    if($object){
        return $object.$property
    } else {
        return $rootObject.$property
    }
}

# The property breadcrumbs
$string = '"Directory Mappings"."SSRS Reports"'
# sp
$delimetedString = $String.Split(".")

$nestedObject = $null

Foreach($breadCrumb in $delimetedString){
    $nestedObject = Get-NestedObject $nestedObject $breadcrumb $settings
}

$nestedObject
```

There are some obvious places where that function could be hardened and documented better but that should give you an idea of what you could do.

Answer (score 0):

What's the use case here? You can split the string as you've described. This will create an array, and you can count the number of elements in the array so that `n` is known.

```
$string = "property1.property2.property3"
$split = $string.split('.')
foreach($i in 0..($split.Count -1)){
    Write-Host "Element $i is equal to $($split[$i])"
    $myString += $split[$i]
}
```

Comment: If I split the string, how do I loop over it such that I stitch it together on the property I need, if it's of `n` length?

Comment: @user3066571 Still not clear on the user case - what you mean by _"stitch it together on the property"_? I've extended the answer to show how you can build a string with all of the parts concatenated into 1 variable `$myString`.... essentially you can do what you want to the parts within the `foreach` loop.

Comment: @gms0ulman OP has yet to comment but I think I know what he wanted. Have a look at my answer to see if you think that might be what they are going for.

Comment: @Matt Aaa I see! I think you've hit the nail on the head with _Invoke-Expression "`$object.$string"_; I find the other code confusing and think OP will as well. Good point on security, if OP does not have end-to-end control of the process.

Comment: Yeah. I don't like the other method but it is safer in a sense