# Set Value of Nested Object Property by Name in PowerShell

Tags: powershell, anonymous-types, powershell-cmdlet, object-graph

I want to set value of nested object property using PowerShell. When you are trying to set the value of the first level properties, it's quiet simple:

```
$propertyName = "someProperty"
$obj.$propertyName = "someValue"  # ← It works
```

For nested properties, it doesn't work:

```
$propertyName = "someProperty.someNestedProperty"
$obj.$propertyName = "someValue"  # ← It doesn't work and raises an error.
```

How to set value of nested object property by name of property using PowerShell?

**MCVE**

For those who want to reproduce the problem, here is a simple example:

```
$Obj= ConvertFrom-Json '{ "A": "x", "B": {"C": "y"} }'
# Or simply create the object:
# $Obj= @{ A = "x"; B = @{C = "y"} }
$Key = "B.C"
$Value = "Some Value"
$Obj.$Key = $Value
```

Run the command and you will receive an error:

> "The property 'B.C' cannot be found on this object. Verify that the
>   property exists and can be set."

**Note:** The code supports any level of nesting.

Comment: It has no way of knowing that you are asking for a nested property. I am trying to find what I think this is a dupe target for. You need to build logic to support nested properties in single strings. This would work but is not what you want `$json.$propertyName.$nestedPropertyName.` since it only would satisfy that one use case. A recursive function is needed iirc

Comment: I think this is what I was thinking of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45174708/powershell-turn-period-delimited-string-into-object-properties/45175340#45175340

Comment: @Matt Thanks for the comment. I'me aware of `$json.$propertyName.$nestedPropertyName`. But it's not based on property name and doesn't satisfy the requirement of resolving property by name at run-time. Also about the linked post, it's *Get*, while I'm looking for *Set*.

Comment: Yeah...I know... Have a look at the linked answer though and see if that gets you in a better direction.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I created `SetValue` and `GetValue` functions to let you get and set a nested property of an object (including a json object) dynamically by name and they work perfectly!

They are recursive functions which resolve the complex property and get the nested property step by step by splitting the nested property name.

**GetValue and SetValue of Nested properties by Name**

```
# Functions
function GetValue($object, $key)
{
    $p1,$p2 = $key.Split(".")
    if($p2) { return GetValue -object $object.$p1 -key $p2 }
    else { return $object.$p1 }
}
function SetValue($object, $key, $Value)
{
    $p1,$p2 = $key.Split(".")
    if($p2) { SetValue -object $object.$p1 -key $p2 -Value $Value }
    else { $object.$p1 = $Value }
}
```

**Example**

In the following example, I set `B.C` dynamically using `SetValue` and get its value by name using the `GetValue` function:

```
# Example
$Obj = ConvertFrom-Json '{ "A": "x", "B": {"C": "y"} }'
# Or simply create the object:
# $Obj = @{ A = "x"; B = @{C = "y"} }
$Key = "B.C"
$Value = "Changed Dynamically!"
SetValue -object $Obj -key $Key -Value $Value
GetValue -object $Obj -key $Key
```

Comment: I would upvote this +20 if I could. This helped by set connectionstrings in an appsettings.json file for a .net project.

Answer (score 5):

Your **[own solutions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46796446/45375) are effective, but do not support *indexed* access** as part of the nested property-access path (e.g., `B[1].C`)

A **simple alternative is to use `Invoke-Expression` (`iex`)**.
While it **[should generally be avoided](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51252636/45375)**, there are exceptional cases where it offers the simplest solution, and this is one of them:

**Assuming you fully control or implicitly trust the property-access string:**

```
$obj = ConvertFrom-Json '{ "A": "x", "B": [ {"C": "y"}, { "C": "z"} ] }'

$propPath = 'B[1].C'

# GET
Invoke-Expression "`$obj.$propPath" # -> 'z'

# SET
$value = 'Some Value'
Invoke-Expression "`$obj.$propPath = `$value"
```

**If you *don't* trust the input**, you can avoid unwanted injection of commands as follows:<sup>[1]</sup>

```
$safePropPath = $propPath -replace '`|\$', '`$&'
Invoke-Expression "`$obj.$safePropPath"
# ...
```

For a **convenience function / ETS method that safely packages the functionality above**, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51863728/45375).

---

<sup>[1] The [regex](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Regular_Expressions)-based [`-replace`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Comparison_Operators#replacement-operator) operation ensures that any `$` characters in the string are escaped as `` `$ ``, to prevent them `Invoke-Expression` from treating them as variable references or subexpressions; similarly, preexisting `` ` `` instances are escaped by *doubling* them.</sup>

Answer (score 3):

May I propose an upgrade to Reza's solution.  With this solution, you can have many level of nested properties.

```
function GetValue($object, [string[]]$keys)
{
    $propertyName = $keys[0]
    if($keys.count.Equals(1)){
        return $object.$propertyName
    }
    else { 
        return GetValue -object $object.$propertyName -key ($keys | Select-Object -Skip 1)
    }
}


function SetValue($object, [string[]]$keys, $value)
{
    $propertyName = $keys[0]
    if($keys.count.Equals(1)) {
        $object.$propertyName = $value
    }
    else { 
        SetValue -object $object.$propertyName -key ($keys | Select-Object -Skip 1) -value $value
    }
}
```

**Usage**

```
$Obj = ConvertFrom-Json '{ "A": "x", "B": {"C": {"D" : "y"}} }'
SetValue $Obj -key "B.C.D".Split(".") -value "z"
GetValue $Obj -key "B.C.D".Split(".")
```

Comment: Thanks Yves for sharing, I checked my answer again and it supports any level of nesting.