# How to enter press square brackets in PowerShell on JSON File

Tags: arrays, json, powershell, member-enumeration

How can I query change value of the "type" string in my JSON file with PowerShell? I can't get to the "type" string.

## JSON file

```
{
"name":  "b",
"compatibilityLevel":  1400,
"model":  {
              "culture":  "c",
              "dataSources":[
                                  {
                                      "type":  "structured"
                                  }
                            ]
         }}
```

## PowerShell

```
$pathToJson =  "C:\Model.bim"

$a = Get-Content $pathToJson | ConvertFrom-Json

$a.'model.dataSources.type' = "c"

$a | ConvertTo-Json -Depth 10  | Set-Content $pathToJson
```

Comment: `$a.model.dataSources = ,@{type = 'C'}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**tl;dr**

```sh
$a.model.dataSources[0].type = 'c'
```

Note the need to specify index `[0]`, because `$a.model.dataSources` is an *array*.

---

AS for **what you tried**:

> `$a.'model.dataSources.type' = "c"`

- You cannot use a property *path* stored in a *string* (`'...'`) to directly access a nested property, because PowerShell interprets `'model.dataSources.type'` as the name of a *single* property.

  - See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51863728/45375) for workarounds.
- Even with that problem corrected, `$a.model.dataSources.type = "c"` does *not* work, because `$a.model.dataSources` returns an *array* of values, and you cannot directly *set* a property on that array's *elements*; instead you must explicitly target the array element of interest, as shown above (`[0]`).

  - Note you can *get* the array elements' `.type` values with `$a.model.dataSources.type`, via a PSv+ feature called [member-access enumeration](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44620191/45375), but that doesn't work on *setting* - by design, to prevent possibly inadvertent updating of all array elements with the same value; see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49410110/45375).