# How to set json property on powershell using a parameter value as the property name

Tags: json, powershell

I'm working on a powershell script where I have to define a certain value for a particular setting that is defined as a parameter. Currently I'm using this:

```
$json = Get-Content $path -Encoding UTF8 | ConvertFrom-Json

$json.AppSettings.RequiresDocument = $value
```

And it seems to work like that, however if I try to include the parameter like so:

```
$json = Get-Content $path -Encoding UTF8 | ConvertFrom-Json

$json.$searchValue = $value
```

I get the error:

```
"The property 
'AppSettings.RequiresDocument' cannot be found on this object. Verify that the property exists and can be set."
```

The property does in fact exist and it's the exact same value as before, but for some reason if I switch it for the parameter, I get this error.

Comment: In short: There is no _built-in_ syntax for nested property access based on a _string value_ containing a property _path_ (e.g. `$prop = 'bar.baz'; $object.$prop` looks for a _single_ property literally named `bar.baz`),  but there are workarounds: see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51863728/45375) to the linked duplicate.