# How do I update an array in an array in a hashtable in Powershell?

Tags: arrays, powershell, hashtable, dsc

I'm using Powershell desired state configuration and have a separate definition document (psd1) I load into memory via

```
$ConfigData = Import-PowerShellDataFile "$Path"
```

where I'd like to update the node names based on an environment variable.  The overall psd1 file shows it's type as a hashtable (name and basetype are below), then allnodes shows up as an array, then nodename as another array.

```
Hashtable  System.Object                                                                                                 
Object[]   System.Array                                                                                                  
Object[]   System.Array
```

Replace doesn't persist (like below). If I try to assign it back to itself or a copy, 'The property 'nodename' cannot be found on this object.  Verify that the property exists yadda'

```
$ConfigData.AllNodes.NodeName -replace 'vms','vmp'
or
$ConfigDataHolder.AllNodes.NodeName = $ConfigData.AllNodes.NodeName -replace 'vms','vmp'
```

Direct reference/assigment doesn't persist, where below's output is still the servername previously, even in a clone scenario.

```
$ConfigData.AllNodes.NodeName[2] = "something"
```

Comment: As an aside: _updating_, as in your title, is the better term to use, because _persisting_ usually connotes updating via a _persistent data store_, such as a file.

Comment: As an aside: the `-replace`  operator never updates the LHS operand _in place_, it only ever _outputs_ (returns) the result of the string replacement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Since you're using property access on *arrays* in order to access values of its *elements*, you're taking advantage of [member-access enumeration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Member-Access_Enumeration).
- However, **member-access enumeration - [by design](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/5271#issuecomment-340285892) - only works for *getting* values, not for *setting* (updating) them**.

  - The **behavior when updating is attempted is *obscure***, unfortunately, as you've experienced:

    - When you try to assign to a member-access-enumerated property *as a whole*, the *error message*  is obscure: it tells you that no such property exists, because on *setting* it only looks at the *array object itself*, even though it does find it on *getting*, when it looks at the arrays *elements*; a minimal example:

      ```bash
       $data = @{ arr = @(@{ subarr = 1, 2 }, @{ subarr = 3, 4 }) } 
       # !! ERROR " property 'subarr' cannot be found on this object"
       $data.arr.subarr = @(42, 43)
      ```
    - If you try a specific index (e.g. `[2]`), but the array that the index is applied to was itself obtained *via member-access enumeration*, the assignment in effect operates on a *temporary array*, and is therefore effectively discarded, quietly; a minimal example:

      ```bash
       $data = @{ arr = @(@{ subarr = 1, 2 }, @{ subarr = 3, 4 }) } 
       # !! IGNORED, because .arr.subarr is the result of
       # !! member-access enumeration.
       $data.arr.subarr[0] = 42
      ```
- The solution is to **target the array elements *individually* for updating**, either with a single index (e.g., `[2]`) or in a *loop*, one by one.

A simplified example:

```bash
$configData = @{
  AllNodes = @(
     @{
       NodeName = @(
        'Node1a', 
        'Node1b'
       ) 
     },
     @{ 
       NodeName = @(
         'Node2a',
         'Node2b'
       ) 
     }
  )
}

# OK: a specific element of *both* arrays involved - .AllNodes and .NodeName -
#     is targeted and can therefore be assigned to.
$configData.AllNodes[0].NodeName[1] = 'NewNode1b'
```

Comment: Thank you so much, this all makes a good bit more sense now that I have a fresher mind.  Also your answer is a phenomenal template for a proper response.  Have a great day!