# Amend XML object using PowerShell

Tags: xml, powershell

I'm trying to edit a xml object in PowerShell but the xml object is quite hard to get to. I've read quite a few posts and articles and they all show easy xml objects or files. And they all work as long as the xml tree is simple and no tags with ':' inside them show up. In my case the xml object is obtained from an Active Directory GPO, through this command:

```
[xml]$report = Get-GPOReport -Guid 'BEE66288-DF38-4E32-A6F6-9DF13BABFDDF' -ReportType XML -Server "fqdn"
```

The xml that generates is quite long and full of sensitive data, so I had to trim it and sanitize it quite a lot, but it gives the idea:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<GPO xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://www.microsoft.com/GroupPolicy/Settings">
  <Computer>
    <VersionDirectory>51</VersionDirectory>
    <VersionSysvol>51</VersionSysvol>
    <Enabled>true</Enabled>
    <ExtensionData>
      <Extension xmlns:q1="http://www.microsoft.com/GroupPolicy/Settings/Files" xsi:type="q1:FilesSettings">
        <q1:FilesSettings clsid="{215B2E53-57CE-475c-80FE-9EEC14635851}">
        </q1:FilesSettings>
      </Extension>
      <Name>Files</Name>
    </ExtensionData>
    <ExtensionData>
      <Extension xmlns:q2="http://www.microsoft.com/GroupPolicy/Settings/ScheduledTasks" xsi:type="q2:ScheduledTasksSettings">
        <q2:ScheduledTasks clsid="{CC63F200-7309-4ba0-B154-A71CD118DBCC}">
          <q2:TaskV2 clsid="{D8896631-B747-47a7-84A6-C155337F3BC8}" name="VBS" image="1" changed="2022-12-01 09:28:19" uid="{6128F739-7B10-4D53-B8B2-4F7D8D518B39}">
            <q2:GPOSettingOrder>1</q2:GPOSettingOrder>
            <q2:Properties action="R" name="VBS" runAs="NT AUTHORITY\System" logonType="S4U">
              <q2:Task version="1.2">
                <q2:RegistrationInfo>
                  <q2:Description>VBS script installs windows update without rebooting</q2:Description>
                </q2:RegistrationInfo>
                <q2:Triggers>
                  <q2:CalendarTrigger>
                    <q2:Enabled>true</q2:Enabled>
                    <q2:StartBoundary>2022-03-27T14:30:00</q2:StartBoundary>
                    <q2:ExecutionTimeLimit>PT4H</q2:ExecutionTimeLimit>
                  </q2:CalendarTrigger>
                </q2:Triggers>
              </q2:Task>
            </q2:Properties>
            <q2:Filters />
          </q2:TaskV2>
          <q2:TaskV2 clsid="{D8896631-B747-47a7-84A6-C155337F3BC8}" name="PS" image="1" changed="2022-12-01 09:28:05" uid="{27A6954B-DC81-42CE-ACA3-FB70CD1DDC98}">
            <q2:GPOSettingOrder>2</q2:GPOSettingOrder>
            <q2:Properties action="R" name="PS" runAs="NT AUTHORITY\System" logonType="S4U">
              <q2:Task version="1.2">
                <q2:RegistrationInfo>
                  <q2:Description>PS script to schedule reboot</q2:Description>
                </q2:RegistrationInfo>
                <q2:Triggers>
                  <q2:CalendarTrigger>
                    <q2:Enabled>true</q2:Enabled>
                    <q2:StartBoundary>2022-03-27T14:30:05</q2:StartBoundary>
                    <q2:ExecutionTimeLimit>PT4H</q2:ExecutionTimeLimit>
                  </q2:CalendarTrigger>
                </q2:Triggers>
              </q2:Task>
            </q2:Properties>
            <q2:Filters />
          </q2:TaskV2>
        </q2:ScheduledTasks>
      </Extension>
      <Name>Scheduled Tasks</Name>
    </ExtensionData>
  </Computer>
</GPO>
```

my goal is to 'select' the lines `<q2:StartBoundary>2022-03-27T14:30:05</q2:StartBoundary>` for each node, then edit them and put them back in the object. Basically I need to change the date/time and save it back in the GPO. I can do the saving back in the GPO by myself. My objective here is to be able to select those lines. I've tried with:

`$nodes = $report.GPO.ChildNodes.Item(0)`

but I can only get as far as the ExtensionData tag. After that the content gets empty, and I have nothing to manipulate. I've also tried

```
$nodes = $report.GPO.Computer.ExtensionData.Extension | Where-Object {$_.type -eq 'q2:ScheduledTasksSettings'}
```

but same thing. Also this:

```
$xpath = "/GPO/Computer/ExtensionData/Extension/q2:ScheduledTasks/q2:TaskV2"
$nodesX = Select-Xml -Xml $report -XPath $xpath
```

but I get an error: `Select-Xml : Namespace Manager or XsltContext needed. This query has a prefix, variable, or user-defined function`

Any hint?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were on the right track. To make your code work:

- **Drill down to the *parent* element(s) of interest** via a **property path**, which - thanks to PowerShell's [member-access enumeration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Member-Access_Enumeration) feature - implicitly iterates over *all* elements that have the same name at a given level of the hierarchy.

  - Do *not* use namespace prefixes such as `q2:` - **PowerShell's convenient adaption of the XML DOM (`[xml]` ([`System.Xml.XmlDocument`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Xml.XmlDocument))) with *dot notation*** (see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49213568/45375)) is ***not* namespace-aware and *ignores* namespaces and their prefixes**.
- **Process the resulting elements with [`ForEach-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/foreach-object)** and update the child element of interest for each.

  - Note that even if the *same* value is to be assigned to all elements of interest, assigning *directly* to a property resulting in/from member-access enumeration does *not* work, because the latter only supports *getting* values - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75025094/45375) for details; e.g.:

    ```bash
    # OK - *getting* all <date> values.
    ([xml] '<d><date>1970</date><date>1971</date></d>').d.date

    # !! NOT SUPPORTED - *setting* all <date> values.
    ([xml] '<d><date>1970</date><date>1971</date></d>').d.date = '2001'
    ```

Therefore:

```bash
$report.GPO.Computer.ExtensionData.Extension.ScheduledTasks.TaskV2.Properties.Task.Triggers.CalendarTrigger | 
  ForEach-Object { $_.StartBoundary = Get-Date -Format s }
```

Note: It doesn't apply to the sample XML at hand, but **it is possible for XML elements to be *inaccessible* with dot notation due to *name collisions***, necessitating a workaround, notably when trying to access `<Item>` child elements on an array of elements resulting from member-access enumeration - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68884190/45375).

---

As for the error you saw with [`Select-Xml`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/select-xml):

- Unlike the dot-notation DOM adaptation, **`Select-Xml` *does* require explicit handling of namespaces** - both by declaring all namespaces up front, and by needing to select elements by *namespace-qualified* names.
- See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74181458/45375) for an example.

Comment: yes, correct. Both solutions work and yours provide less code too. hence I've used it.

Answer (score 1):

Try xml linq

```
using assembly System 
using assembly System.Linq
using assembly System.Xml.Linq 

$inputFilename = "c:\temp\test.xml"
$outputFilename = "c:\temp\test1.xml"

$reader = [System.IO.StreamReader]::new($inputFilename)
# skip first line with utf-16
$reader.ReadLine()
$xDoc = [System.Xml.Linq.XDocument]::Load($reader)
$today = [DateTime]::Now
$tasksV2 = $xDoc.Descendants().Where( {$_.Name.LocalName -eq "TaskV2"})
foreach($taskV2 in $tasksV2)
{
   $name = $taskV2.Attribute("name").Value

   $startBoundary = $xDoc.Descendants().Where( {$_.Name.LocalName -eq "StartBoundary"})
   $oldDate = $startBoundary[0].Value
   $todayStr = $today.ToString("yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss")
   Write-Host "Task Name = " $name ",Old Date = " $oldDate ",Today Date = " $todayStr
   $startBoundary.SetValue($todayStr)
}
$xDoc.Save($outputFilename)
```

Comment: many thanks!! That worked.. by the way I guess that $records variable can be left out, correct?

Comment: Yes record is not needed.  I wasn't clear if you just need the startBoundary or other info.  You can use Descendants to just get startboundary from the doc.

Comment: ok, got it. In my case the input and output file are the same. But the xDoc.Save() method throws an error saying that "The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process." Am I bound to save it with different name and then delete the original or is there another solution? I read that there should be a close method somewhere but in C#. I don't see any close method in PowerShell..  else I will write two more lines to save with different name, then delete, then rename.. and thanks again

Comment: XDocument does not have a close method.  So writing to new file and rename is a good solution.

Comment: sorry to bug you again.. the sample xml used above contains only 2 TaskV2 but in reality the real xml file contains 3. I only need  to modify the first 2, not the third. I thought I could simply do like this:

    foreach($taskV2 in $tasksV2.Where({$_.Attribute('name').Value -ne 'wsus-extraMaintenance'}))
    {
       rest of  the code
    }
and from console it seems it works, as I only get two Write-Hosts as per your code. But the xml file written at the end has amended also the one $taskV2 that was excluded. How to exclude a TaskV2 from the rest?

Comment: You can force a psobject to an array by surrounding with `@(.......)`.  So you can use :  @($StartBoundary)[1]

Comment: xml linq is the newer net library for xml.  XmlDocument is the older net library that take more instructions to do same as linq.  I have more statements because my code returns more values.

Comment: it's a pity SO does not allow multiple answers. Again, both solutions work, I've chosen the one by mklement0 simply because shorter. Nothing else.